# desctucrure object in JS {data: {user: {id, role}}} = useSession() throw an erorr

Tags: destructuring, next-auth

How can an object be destructured in a JS that can be initialized as undefined. For example, I need to destructure the session object that is returned by the useSession hook.

```js
{data: {user: {id, role}}} = useSession()
```

throws an error if useSession returns `undefined | null` .

all I can do is write it this way in JSX

```js
data?.user?.role === 'admin'
```

could I write in this way without an erorr if `data == undefined` ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this component to your app.js file :

```js
function Auth({ children }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { status } = useSession({
    required: true,
    onUnauthenticated() {
      router.push("/sign-in");
    },
  });

  if (status === "loading") {
    return 
      <div>
       Loading...
      </div>
  }
  return children;
}
```

Then add `auth` property to every page in which you need the `session` to be defined otherwise the user will be redirected to `/sign-in` 
 example :

```js
const Page = () => {
//...
}
Page.auth={}
```

Finally in `MyApp` component you return `<Component {...pageProps} />` with condition:

```js
{
  Component.auth ? (
    <Auth>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Auth>
  ) : (
    <>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}
```

This will wrap every page that has the `auth` property with the `<Auth>` component and this latter will do the work for it so `session` will be always defined